# POSTing a PHP variable as a value in a form

Tags: php, forms, post, radio-button

I have an html form consisting of just radio buttons. The 2nd line of the following is in a loop, therefore assume there are multiple radio buttons. The value of each radio button printed out is a PHP variable.

```
<form action='delFile.php' method='post'>
<input type='radio' value=" . $row['fileName'] . " name='del' />
<input type='submit' value='Delete' /></form>
```

My question is:
How can I, on the action page, call the selected radio.
I would normally use:

```
$foo = $_POST['valueHere'];
```

...but I don't know the value.

Maybe this isn't even possible? I want to know the fileName from the radio so that I can delete a row in a MySQL database on the action page. If I'm going about this the wrong way completely then please point me in the right direction :)

Any help is appreciated - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST variables check the name of the fields, not the value.  So, this will give you the value of whichever radio button was selected:

```
$foo = $_POST['del'];
```

Comment: Oh wow! I would have never thought to try the name.
I was also worried my question didn't make any sense...
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
$foo = $_POST['del'];
```